# Websocket auto-self-sign certificate shows ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: web, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im trying to connect my blazor app to my server.

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime js
@inject HttpClient h

<butt @onclick="Connect">connect</butt>

@code {
public async Task Connect()
    {
        var cliente = new ClientWebSocket();
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
        Uri uri = new Uri("wss://192.168.1.39:7000");
        await cliente.ConnectAsync(uri,cts.Token);
    }
}
```

im using this library :

> System.Net.WebSockets.Client

and it shows this error :

> dotnet.6.0.4.p9lwyok8ai.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.1.39:7000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

the server its working good.

Comment: Self signed certificates are invalid.  Is that unexpected to you?

Comment: so i cant  use a websocked without an entity that sign the certificate ? is there any way to use the webshocked conection?

Comment: You  could use `ws://` instead of `wss://`.  You could get a domain and a certificate.

Comment: i used ws but it shows me this error : dotnet.6.0.4.p9lwyok8ai.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:7079/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://192.168.1.39:7000/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

Comment: You can only use `ws://` from a `http://` page.  You can't use `https://` on localhost without clicking through scary warnings.

Comment: ye im seen how to change my blazor page to http,  u know a methot ?  and thanx for the help

Comment: While changing to http might be OK for development, you'll want to get a domain and valid certificate for when other people use it.

Comment: Yep ik, but 4 now its just a "local web" for the company. in a future will add those certificates, but for now i dont need them. You know a methot to use http instead of https im just searching and i dont see any result. thanx 4 all dude :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webshocket secure "wss//" cant be used by auto-self signed certificate, then i cahnge the https to http and i used webshocket "ws//" to use http instead of https u need to change Client\Properties\launchSetings.json on "applicationUrl":"ur http" and the same on Server\Properties\launchSetings.json